# Alternative dependencies (fall back) in setup.py

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

Say I want to install `pyodbc`. It can't be build on some Windows machines but there's an alternative - `pypyodbc` which is pure python implementation of `pyobdc`.

Is there a way to specify `install_requires=["pyobdc"]` for `setuptools.setup` with falling back to `pypyodbc` if the former package wasn't installed?

UPD: My solution for this particular situation:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup

if sys.platform.startswith("win"):
    pyodbc = "pypyodbc>=1.2.0"
else:
    pyodbc = "pyodbc>=3.0.7"

...

setup(
      ...
      install_requires=[pyobdc]
      )
```

But I still look for a more general solution.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your approach.  This looks valid according to the docs. https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Doing what you are already doing seems like a common recommendation, but since this question is the top google hit for this sort of question, I'll point out that `install_requires` supports a fairly intricate mini-language which is specified in [PEP 508](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/):

```
install_requires = [
    'pypyodbc>=1.2.0;platform_system=="Windows"',
    'pyodbc>=3.0.7;platform_system!="Windows"'
]
```

[In a comment to a related question](/questions/21082091/install-requires-based-on-python-version#comment69951916_21082173), user [Marius Gedminas](/users/110151/marius-gedminas) notes that having your `install_requires` computed in code could have some adverse effects, so the above should be preferred to avoid that problem.

(On the other hand, https://hynek.me/articles/conditional-python-dependencies/ laments some pretty serious portability problems if you have to support old versions of `setuptools`.)

Comment: So far I have not been able to find any specification or practical example of a syntax like the `foo || bar` syntax in Debian packages to say you want either `foo` or `bar` to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is the correct one for this situation. It is the best and more flexible way at the moment to achieve this task.

Answer (score -1):

In setup there is no try A fallback B. The manual try is like this:

```
try:
   import pyodbc# i didn't test this
except ImportError:
   import subprocess
   import sys
   test=subprocess.run([sys.executable,'-m','pip','install','pypyodbc>=1.2.0'])
   if test.returncode:
        subprocess.run([sys.executable,'-m','pip','install','pyodbc>=3.0.7'])
```