# How do I specify two alternative requirements with setuptools by pip package name?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, setuptools, distutils

I want to write a `setup.py` file using `setuptools`. My package depends on `tensorflow`, but there are two different pip packages that fulfill the requirement, `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu`. If I just put `tensorflow` in my `setup(..., install_requires=["tensorflow"])`, then installation will fail if the the user has instead installed the `tensorflow-gpu` pip package on their system.

The `imp` module can't be used to check (as in this answer: [How to check if a python module exists without importing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050281/how-to-check-if-a-python-module-exists-without-importing-it)), because the *import* name of the module is `tensorflow` regardless of which *pip package* the user installed. So how does setuptools (and therefore distutils) detect which pip package was installed? I've dug through the source a bit, but can't find the place that it checks.

*Note, I am not planning on hacking setuptools to accept either. I just want to know what method it is using to detect the package, so I can use that same method in my `setup.py` to manually set the install_requires param to the correct version. (i.e. like this: [Alternative dependencies (fall back) in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060421/alternative-dependencies-fall-back-in-setup-py))

Answer (score 2):

I [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660880/7976758) a similar question recently. You need to distinguish one TF from the other. I don't know TF enough to help with the detail but most part of the code should be like this:

```
kw = {}
try:
    import tensorflow
except ImportError:  # There is no one, declare dependency
    kw['install_requires'] = ['tensorflow']
else:
    if is_gpu(tensorflow):
        kw['install_requires'] = ['tensorflow-gpu']
    else:
        kw['install_requires'] = ['tensorflow']

setup(
    …
    **kw
)
```

Comment: Yea, in the end I did something like this...but this can't be the method that setuptools is using because it's module-specific. Is it checking the pip database somehow?

Comment: There is no 'pip database'. I think setuptools and Co scan *.dist-info directories in site-packages.

Comment: It should be noted that this otherwise awesome answer fails to scale to wheels, which are unable to perform install-time logic of this sort. What can you do, eh? `setuptools`. `setuptools` never changes.