# setuptools: force version of another package (if present) while not forcing installation of this package (when not present)

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

During development of Pylint, we encountered [interesting problem related to non-dependency that may break `pylint` package](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1318).

Case is following:

- `python-future` had a conflicting alias to `configparser` package. [Quoting official docs](http://python-future.org/whatsnew.html#what-s-new-in-version-0-16-0-2016-10-27):

  > This release removes the configparser package as an alias for ConfigParser on Py2 to improve compatibility with Lukasz Langa’s backported configparser package. Previously python-future and the configparser backport clashed, causing various compatibility issues. (Issues #118, #181)
- `python-future` itself **is not** a dependency of Pylint

What would be a standard way to enforce *if python-future is present, force it to 0.16 or later* limitation? I want to avoid defining dependency as `future>=0.16` - by doing this I'd force users to install package that they don't need and won't use in a general case.

Comment: It sounds like what you're describing is simply a bug in `python-future` that might affect any code that does `import configparser`.  Is that correct?  If so, it doesn't seem like it makes sense to try to "fix" it with your own dependency lists.

Comment: @BrenBarn well, clients disagree. You can see quite a heated discussion under linked issue. That's why I asked this question - to figure out whether there is a smart way to handle this highly unusual case that gave a lot of people trouble.

Comment: Do you have an answer to the question raised towards the end of that discussion: "what does require future or futures?"  It seems like understanding that would be quite important for understanding how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
kw = {}
try:
    import future
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    kw['install_requires'] = ['future>=0.16']

setup(
    …
    **kw
)
```

Comment: **This.** This is *almost* there. As [pradyunsg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1931274/pradyunsg) notes, this approach fails to scale to wheels. Assuming a local dev environment with `python-future` installed, wheel users will be forced to install `python-future` >= 0.16. That's hardly the worst thing to happen, however. A small price must be paid for a mostly-worky solution.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround for this issue is to define this requirement only for the `all` target, so only if someone adds `pylint[all]>=1.2.3` as a requirement they will have futures installed/upgraded.

At this moment I don't know another way to "ignore or upgrade" a dependency.

Also, I would avoid adding Python code to `setup.py` in order to make it "smart",... is a well known distribution anti-pattern ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported way to tell pip or setuptools that a package needs to satisfy a constraint only if installed. There might be some hacks but I imagine they'll all be fragile and likely breaking in the future versions of pip/setuptools.

Honestly, the only *good* way is to document it for users that `future < 16.0` would break pylint, in the appropriate location in the documentation.

---

Making your `setup.py` script contain conditional dependencies is something that has been strongly discouraged for some time now. Once a wheel is built, the package is installed with the same dependency information as the wheel holds - setup.py is not run on the end-user's system, only on the packager's system, which means any setup.py hack (like @phd's) would not be useful (since pylint distributes wheels).

Comment: Due to the inexpressiveness of the `install_requires` parameter, [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)'s [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44660880/2809027) is the *only* meaningful means the Python community has of specifying conditional dependencies. Admonishing developers for doing so when [circumstances dictate](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1318) they absolutely *must* isn't particularly helpful. What *would* have been helpful is an extension of phd's approach adding `setup.py` and application logic handling wheel-specific edge cases.